# 4.0.2 addons will not install. Hard ops and Procedural Crowds

Tags: customization

I accidentally deleted Procedural Crowds and Hard Ops by clicking the checkmark in Preferences in 4.0.2
I tried to reinstall these addons and after clicking "install" but the addons never appear as usual. I tried using Power Backup addon to restore addons and preferences. That didn't work.
I tried deleting 4.0.2 and reinstalling it and clicking "use 3.65 settings on splash page. That didn't work; it seemed to have the exact settings after I originally deleted the addons initially by mistake.
I tried installing the addons again and after installing, can't be found in preferences.

Comment: first of all - you do not delete add-ons by clicking the checkmark. You just disable them. If you would have clicked the checkmark again, they would be enabled again. The add-ons will only be deleted, if you hit that "remove" button in the add-ons settings. You should go to your add-ons folder of your blender file and delete the add-on folders there, and then install them again.

Comment: Thank you Chris.  Yes, normally but they also disappeared so I can't just re-check it.   I have gone to the blender file and sometimes the addon is listed but not appearing in the preferences panel.  Sometimes they are not there even in the blender file. I tried deleting addon and re-installing to no avail.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhlvLzMt73c

Comment: Solved.   Nice youtube solve